# New Test User Validation Process

Tags: testing, ios7

I have created a new test user. The validation process asks me for a credit card (like any other regular user). This happens since I have IOS7 installed . is it normal? Thanks. 
A comment for Apple: A comment: In App Purchase Test process is very troublesome.

Comment: please add more information (samples of your code, what exactly is going wrong, what exactly you'd like to have happen)

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. I did enter the CC information, and everything worked properly. Additionally, I had to change the Apple address to my own address for validation to work. I suppose this is needed to test some of the CC handshaking, etc. But that's just speculation on my part. On a related topic, I'm wondering how to sign out and then sign on to a test user on iOS7, specifically on the simulator. Is In App Purchase even possible on the simulator?